# Find row where its id is in a list and count is the same

Tags: sql, database

I am trying to find a Conversation from UserConversation table row where UserConversation.userId is in a list and also find the rows of UserConversation.userId matching is of a certain number.

So I have a Conversation table.  I have a UserConversation table with (userId, conversationId) fields.  My question is how do I get UserConversation.conversationId where userId's are in a list and the matching list.size is same:

I have the following query so far as a sample:

```
select uc.conversationid from userconversation uc where uc.userid in(3, 14, 23, 13978, 18488) group by uc.conversationid having count(*)=5
```

but this query gives me other UserConversation.conversationId where there could be additional userIds in the conversation.  I just want to qualify it with a count also.

Below is a sample:

My Conversation table looks like this:

```
select * from conversation where id=18

id | name            | ownerid
------------------------------
18 | personal group 3|

select * from userconversation where conversationid=18

conversationId | userId
-----------------------
18             | 3
18             | 14
18             | 23
18             | 13978
18             | 18488
```

Now I want to find the conversation that has the userIds 3,14,23,13978,18488 and only conversation that has that exact number of users. I should only get 18 as conversationId and not other conversation that may also have those plus other users.

Anybody know how to do that in SQL?

thanks

Comment: show some sample data and the expected result.

Comment: @vkp I have added a sample.

Comment: what's the output you wanna get?

Comment: @JCBorlagdan I want to get the value "18" for the result from the select sql query which based on the "select * from userconversation where conversationid=18" query shows there are 5 userIds that match my first sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for since your question isn't clear but try this if this is the one you want.

```
SELECT userId FROM userconversation uc
INNER JOIN conversation c
ON uc.conversationId = c.Id
```

Comment: That's not the query I am looking for.  Let me restate my problem.  How do I get based on my 2nd sample sql query the only conversationId which only has the users I specifed in my first sql query?

Comment: hmm, try select DISTINCT(uc.conversationid) from userconversation uc where uc.userid in(3, 14, 23, 13978, 18488) group by uc.conversationid having count(*)=5 

if your 1st query is correct, the word DISTINCT will solve your problem,